# Which game is this screenshot from?

Tags: game-identification

I have this screenshot from somewhere, and was wondering what is the game he is playing.

[image: Screenshot of the game]

Comment: It's definitely from the Battlefield series, unsure about which one though. Looks like 3, though.

Comment: It's most definitely Battlefield 3. Battlefield 4 has a different HUD and that looks like one of the Back to Karkand maps if I'm not mistaken.

Answer (score 37):

This game is Battlefield 3 for the PC.

Comment: Was almost gonna say "how do you know it's for the PC?" Then I saw the keybinding haha

Comment: @Ben That classic "Aha!" moment.